# Deploying application to virtual directory via CD pipeline

Tags: iis

When I try to deploy app to virtual directory, I get this error. I tried many options, it does not seem to work.

site  abc.xyz.com  is existing
Virtual director dcs is existing
Physical path is existing

2023-06-08T18:35:27.1228385Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list app "abc.xyz.com/dcs"
2023-06-08T18:35:27.3571522Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  add app
/site.name:"abc.xyz.com" /path:"/dcs" /physicalPath:"S:\xxx\yyy"

2023-06-08T18:35:27.5197446Z ERROR ( message:Failed to add duplicate collection element "/dcs". )

Comment: `message:Failed to add duplicate collection element "/dcs"` This error usually occurs when the virtual directory you are trying to create already exists. If the virtual directory exists, you need to delete it or choose a different path for your deployment.